# How to hold subcategory division while i move out of category division?

Tags: javascript

```css
.category-list{
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;
    width:20%;
    margin-left:50px;
   
}
#subcat1 , #subcat2 , #subcat3 , #subcat4 , #subcat5 , #subcat6 , #subcat7 , #subcat8 , #subcat9 , #subcat10 {
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;
    left:350px;
    width:50%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="category-list" id="list-category">
     <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" onmouseout="document.getElementById('subcat1').style.display = 'none';" onmouseover="document.getElementById('subcat1').style.display = 'block';" >First item</a>
        <div class="subcat" id="subcat1" style="display:none;" >
             <div class="list-group">
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">First item</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">First item</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">First item</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

this is letting subcategory division go away once i move out of category division
I want to create a category and subcategory like things as in a shopping website 
Thanks in advance

Comment: The subcategory division goes away because of **onmouseout** event :`onmouseout="document.getElementById('subcat1').style.display = 'none';"` If you don't want this behavior, remove **onmouseout** event

Comment: Why don't you check some ready CSS solutions [as this one](https://codepen.io/philhoyt/pen/ujHzd)? And, instead of `#subcat1 , #subcat2 , #subcat3 , #subcat4 , #subcat5 , #subcat6 , #subcat7 , #subcat8 , #subcat9 , #subcat10` you can use just **.subcat**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.subcat` disappers because of

`onmouseout="document.getElementById('subcat1').style.display = 'none';"`.

You can use

`onmouseover="document.getElementById('subcat1').style.display = 'block';"`

on `.subcat` too.

```css
.category-list{
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;
    width:20%;
    margin-left:50px;
   
}
.subcat{
    margin-left: 60px;
    position:fixed;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="category-list" id="list-category">
     <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" onmouseout="document.getElementById('subcat1').style.display = 'none';" onmouseover="document.getElementById('subcat1').style.display = 'block';" >First item</a>
        <div class="subcat" id="subcat1" style="display:none;"  onmouseout="document.getElementById('subcat1').style.display = 'none';" onmouseover="document.getElementById('subcat1').style.display = 'block';" >
             <div class="list-group">
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">First item</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">First item</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">First item</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```